# Does Ind-completion commute with finite limits?

Tags: infinity-categories, limits-and-colimits, stable-category

The broad and vague question is in the title. The more precise question is:

Say $\{\mathcal{C}_i\}$ is a finite diagram of (essentially small) stable $\infty$-categories and exact functors with limit $\mathcal{C}$. Is $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C}) \simeq \lim \mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C_i})$ ? If not, are there reasonable conditions under which this does work?

[Note: By Theorem 1.1.4.4 in Lurie's "Higher algebra," the limit $\mathcal{C}$ above can be computed in the large world of $\infty$-categories, or in the world of stable $\infty$-categories and exact functors.]

Answer (score 9):

Let $D$ be the derived category of k-vector spaces, and let $C$ be the part consisting of bounded chain complexes of finite-dimensional vector spaces.  $D = \mathit{Ind}(C)$.

Let $P$ be a finite partially ordered set whose nerve is a circle, and consider the constant diagrams $\underline{C}$ and $\underline{D}$ shaped like $P$.  The limit of $\underline{D}$ is the category of local systems on a circle.  The limit of $\underline{C}$ is the category of local systems on a circle, with bounded finite-dimensional fibers.

I think (local systems on a circle) is not the same as Ind(local systems with bounded finite-dimensional fibers on a circle).  The former category contains a compact object whose group of endomorphisms is infinite-dimensional: the local system corresponding to the free rank one k[Z]-module.